# Translate ternary operator into if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm still learning the javascript language and I ran into this bit of code. I was wondering if anyone would possibly "translate" it into an if/else statement to make it easier for me to understand what's happening? Thanks!

```
var offsetX = (w < 0) ? w : 0;
var offsetY = (h < 0) ? h : 0;
```

Comment: There: `var offsetX = Math.min(0, w);` ;)

Comment: `var offsetX = 0; if(w < 0) { offsetX = w }`

Comment: `var offsetX = (w < 0) ? w : 0;` ===> `if(w < 0) offsetX = w; else offsetX = 0;`

Comment: `var offsetX; if (w < 0) { offsetX = w; } else { offsetX = 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var offsetX, offsetY;
if(w<0)
    offsetX = w;
else
    offsetX = 0;

if(h<0)
    offsetY = h;
else
    offsetY = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators always take the form `condition ? true expr : false expr`. Check this doc for an explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

So, in your case, the expression before colon (`:`) becomes the part of `if` condition and the expression after colon becomes the part of `else` condition:

```
// declare offsetX
var offsetX

if (w < 0) {
  offsetX = w;
} else {
  offsetX = 0;
}

// for offsetY has the same concept
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
if (w<0)
{
    offsetX = w;
}
else
{
    offsetX = 0;
}
```

Same for `offsetY`